# How to insert entire value of $_POST in mysql database without writing like $_POST['something']

Tags: php

I have html data in an array like

```
Array( [postedMsg] => <font color="blue">Blogger Wallpost</font>
       [nbsp;<div_dir] => "ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on"><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"></div><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"></div><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"></div><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JrRECIxhi4s/TzpAs4lmgnI/AAAAAAAAAD4/KWcPpfXEGtU/s1600/800px-Cooked_Poha.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">image</a></div><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">Happy Blogger Wallpost</div><br></div><div class="blogger-post-footer">image src</div>
     )
```

I try to use the code like

```
 foreach($htmlpostedMsg AS $key => $value) 
  {
     $htmlpostedMsg[$key] = $value;
  }
  print_r($htmlpostedMsg[$key]);
```

It prints only last part like

```
 \"ltr\" style=\"text-align: left;\" trbidi=\"on\"><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JrRECIxhi4s/TzpAs4lmgnI/AAAAAAAAAD4/KWcPpfXEGtU/s1600/800px-Cooked_Poha.jpg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\">image src</a></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\">Happy Blogger Wallpost</div><br></div><div class=\"blogger-post-footer\">image src</div>\n
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. It's such a mess currently that I don't even know where to start editing it.

Comment: Please format that code, so we have a chance of understanding it.

Comment: I tried to edit your post but can't figure it out: are all those styles in your original code, or are they taken from where you copied it? (maybe a formatted html page). Please reformat your code as it is illegible so far

Comment: What is the intended purpose of your statement, $htmlpostedMsg[$key] = $value? In the context, it makes no sense.

Comment: I suspect you're copy/pasting from some js-highlighted code on an html page. It's really hard to format it, and to tell what's the real code and what's the styling applied to the page. Please post the _original_ code. Need help on this

Comment: @DamienPirsy: you deserve a medal just for trying!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use extract method to get associative array from the POST value

Say you have post array like $_POST['name'],$_POST['email']

```
       extract($_POST);
       echo $name;// 'name you entered';
       echo $email;// 'email you entered';
```

Comment: This is a rather dangerous method if you don't know what you're doing. The user can insert any variables to the script they want. Besides, all it does is save a couple of keystrokes so you don't have to write `$_POST[ 'name' ]` in full.

Comment: There is a built in function for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php

Answer (score -2):

You can do [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) on the `$_POST` and then store in mysql table.

Comment: That answers the title, but not the question ;-)

Comment: at first question is messed up. so I have answered for the title. any how title should be relative to question. :)